# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Upgrading spring boot to 2.5.x or greater

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, build.gradle

Error details and `build.gradle`

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-05-17T13:19:21.396Z","@version":"1","message":"Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.marksandspencer.paymentsapi.configuration.ExceptionHandling#handleGenericException$spg_payments_api(Exception, WebRequest)","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-5","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.Visibilities\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.Visibility.compareTo(Visibility.kt:23)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.DescriptorVisibility.compareTo(DescriptorVisibility.kt:66)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.DescriptorVisibilities.compare(DescriptorVisibilities.java:382)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.findMaxVisibility(OverridingUtil.java:985)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.computeVisibilityToInherit(OverridingUtil.java:944)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.resolveUnknownVisibilityForMember(OverridingUtil.java:909)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$generateFakeOverrides$1.addFakeOverride(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:326)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.createAndBindFakeOverride(OverridingUtil.java:741)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.createAndBindFakeOverrides(OverridingUtil.java:573)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.generateOverridesInFunctionGroup(OverridingUtil.java:504)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.generateFakeOverrides(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:318)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.computeNonDeclaredFunctions(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:301)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:277)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.access$computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:228)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:251)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:251)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:578)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:651)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.getContributedFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:329)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.addFunctionsAndPropertiesTo(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:360)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeDescriptors(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:115)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:268)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:267)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:278)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(ResolutionScope.kt:50)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl.getMembers(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:56)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:162)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:162)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDeclaredNonStaticMembers(KClassImpl.kt:162)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:171)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:171)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getAllNonStaticMembers(KClassImpl.kt:171)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:177)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:177)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getAllMembers(KClassImpl.kt:177)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getMembers(KClassImpl.kt:195)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.getFunctions(KClasses.kt:89)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:136)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.MethodParameter$KotlinDelegate.getGenericReturnType(MethodParameter.java:915)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.MethodParameter$KotlinDelegate.access$000(MethodParameter.java:866)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:510)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.getGenericType(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:343)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:183)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:428)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:75)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:142)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1327)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)\r\n"}
    {"@timestamp":"2022-05-17T13:19:21.407Z","@version":"1","message":"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.collections.MapsKt.createMapBuilder()Ljava/util/Map;] with root cause","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-5","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.collections.MapsKt.createMapBuilder()Ljava/util/Map;\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.Visibilities.<clinit>(Visibilities.kt:56)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.Visibility.compareTo(Visibility.kt:23)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.DescriptorVisibility.compareTo(DescriptorVisibility.kt:66)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.DescriptorVisibilities.compare(DescriptorVisibilities.java:382)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.findMaxVisibility(OverridingUtil.java:985)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.computeVisibilityToInherit(OverridingUtil.java:944)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.resolveUnknownVisibilityForMember(OverridingUtil.java:909)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$generateFakeOverrides$1.addFakeOverride(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:326)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.createAndBindFakeOverride(OverridingUtil.java:741)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.createAndBindFakeOverrides(OverridingUtil.java:573)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.generateOverridesInFunctionGroup(OverridingUtil.java:504)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.generateFakeOverrides(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:318)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.computeNonDeclaredFunctions(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:301)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:277)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.access$computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:228)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:251)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:251)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:578)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:651)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.getContributedFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:329)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.addFunctionsAndPropertiesTo(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:360)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeDescriptors(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:115)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:268)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:267)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:278)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(ResolutionScope.kt:50)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl.getMembers(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:56)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:162)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:162)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDeclaredNonStaticMembers(KClassImpl.kt:162)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:171)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:171)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getAllNonStaticMembers(KClassImpl.kt:171)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:177)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:177)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getAllMembers(KClassImpl.kt:177)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getMembers(KClassImpl.kt:195)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.getFunctions(KClasses.kt:89)\r\n\tat kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:136)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.KotlinReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(KotlinReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.java:50)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:55)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterName(MethodParameter.java:712)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.updateNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:174)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.getNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:154)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)\r\n"}
```

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21' // Required for Kotlin integration  
    ext.spring_boot_version = '2.6.6'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // Required for Kotlin integration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'kotlin' // Required for Kotlin integration
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin
apply plugin: "jacoco"

configurations {
    testRuntime
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.6"
}

test {
    jacoco {
      //  append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/results/jacoco/test.exec")
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
  //  executionData = files("$buildDir/results/jacoco/test.exec", "$buildDir/results/jacoco/cucumber.exec")
    executionData.from(files("$buildDir/results/jacoco/test.exec", "$buildDir/results/jacoco/cucumber.exec"))
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
    }

    dependsOn test
    dependsOn 'runEndToEndTests'
}



task runEndToEndTests() {
    dependsOn startAndPopulateDatabase, assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        runEndToEndTestMain()
    }
    finalizedBy clearTestDockerImages
}

task runEndToEndTestsExistingDatabase() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        runEndToEndTestMain()
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlin_version}" // Required for Kotlin integration
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlin_version}"
   // implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.7'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc"    
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.27.2'
    testImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.6'
    testImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.6'   
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    // end::tests[]
}
```